# MySQL INNER JOIN ordering by multiple matches first

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables

```
gifts - a list of products
tags - a list of tags that can be applied to products
tags_gifts - a join for gifts and tags if they are applicable
```

Here's two tag examples (id, name):

```
508 - jewellery
7 - gold
```

I have the following SQL for results:

```
SELECT * FROM gifts 
LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
WHERE published = '1' AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '508' OR tags_gifts.tag_id = '7') ) 
GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 
ORDER BY gift_popularity DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

This works fine and shows all results with matches of 'jewellery' or 'gold' and orders them by popularity, but I'd like to show multiple matches first eg. A product matches both tags, and then order the remaining products by popularity.

Can't figure out how to do this - thanks

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Just a remark: Change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, because you are only looking for existing gift tags. (The WHERE clause renders your join an inner join implicitly, but to call it LEFT JOIN makes it look like your statement may not do the thing it was supposed to do.)

Comment: @Strawberry: I don't think the question was so hard to understand.

Comment: I didn't say it was !

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I will try them out tomorrow. Thorsten in response to your comment about using INNER, I am using LEFT because a gift doesn't necessarily have to have a tag it can be returned by. If not a MATCH AGAINST will be used in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  use `COUNT()` in `ORDER BY` ,so if count returns 2 it means product has both tags

```
SELECT * FROM gifts 
LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
WHERE published = '1' AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '508' OR tags_gifts.tag_id = '7') ) 
GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC , gift_popularity DESC
 LIMIT 0,20
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work and will be fast, you can adjust "a LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0" as you wish.

> ```
> SELECT a.* FROM (
>     SELECT * FROM gifts 
>     LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
>     INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
>     WHERE published = '1' AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '508' AND tags_gifts.tag_id = '7')  ) 
>     GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 
>     ORDER BY gift_popularity DESC  
> )  UNION (
>     SELECT * FROM gifts 
>     LEFT JOIN tags_gifts ON tags_gifts.gift_id = gifts.gift_id 
>     INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_gifts.tag_id 
>     WHERE published = '1' AND ( (tags_gifts.tag_id = '508' OR tags_gifts.tag_id = '7') ) 
>     GROUP BY gifts.gift_id 
>     ORDER BY gift_popularity DESC
> ) a LIMIT 0,20
> ```

Comment: So if I was looking to match 4-5 tags would I need to do 4-5 unions? Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you want to order the results in this manner: all-4-tags-match > any-3-tags-match > any-2-tags-match .... Then you should use this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22910549/1516904